# After adding validation for Paperclip 4.1, image still fails to upload, yet Rails says listing was updated successfully

Tags: image-processing, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip-validation

When reviewing the server log, it appears the file is being uploaded, then immediately deleted.  When the process completes, I receive the message "Listing updated successfully" and there is no image, thumbnail or default image showing.  Why is this happening?  How do I correct it?

Note:  Using new validation requirements (as per paperclip 4.1).  Tried rolling back to previous paperclip versions to avoid all the bugs associated with new release, but to no avail.

Server log:

```
Started PATCH "/listings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-08 15:45:49 -0700
Processing by ListingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UMFEym5teuWw4rth+BAF1XSP1iKbhXrghK+s69ItOCo=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"Adidas Running Shoes", "description"=>"Give your athlete a hug for their feet with Adidas's new line of runner hugs.", "price"=>"345.53", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001010f2858 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140408-15455-199ppzx>, @original_filename="DSC04408.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"DSC04408.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update Listing", "id"=>"1"}
  Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1p9hrde.JPG'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200" '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q20140408-15455-xkdr1h'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q20140408-15455-xkdr1h'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q.JPG[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q20140408-15455-q28sme'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1x4xd5q20140408-15455-q28sme'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/cn/1g54l3tx7710q5rn06m3mfhc0000gn/T/c7def7d234a905f0957b430542e72dcb20140408-15455-1el61o.JPG'
  SQL (2.5ms)  UPDATE "listings" SET "image_updated_at" = ?, "image_file_name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "listings"."id" = 1  [["image_updated_at", Tue, 08 Apr 2014 22:45:49 UTC +00:00], ["image_file_name", "DSC04408.JPG"], ["updated_at", Tue, 08 Apr 2014 22:45:51 UTC +00:00]]
[paperclip] deleting /Users/donovanwilleto/Code/xchange/public/system/listings/images/000/000/001/original/DSC04408.JPG
[paperclip] deleting /Users/donovanwilleto/Code/xchange/public/system/listings/images/000/000/001/medium/DSC04408.JPG
[paperclip] deleting /Users/donovanwilleto/Code/xchange/public/system/listings/images/000/000/001/thumb/DSC04408.JPG
   (27.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/listings/1
Completed 302 Found in 2372ms (ActiveRecord: 29.8ms)


Started GET "/listings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-08 15:45:51 -0700
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered listings/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: Can you share the `show` view code?

Comment: @KirtiThroat - My rails instructor solved it using this command: rake db:migrate:reset.  Apparently it was looking for information from a previous migration and could not proceed without it.  Works fine now.

Comment: Alright then, post an answer to your own question stating how you resolved it.

Comment: Also, please include the code, otherwise this is not useful Q&A for future searchers and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was migration related.

Ran

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

to resolve.

Rebooted server.  Image now showing.